Application getting crashed on Azure App service
We have a ASP:P1V3 and 5 app services and one of the app service has a problem . The application gets restarted with a below message .
Your application was recycled as the BYOS storage settings changed.
We checked the activity log and see there is deployifnotexist policy gets triggered and created a storage file share on azure app service path mappings configuration file which crashes the application


Thanks,
Vinod J
We tried to delete the mount share and then it works but after sometime again we see a mount is attached automatically and then application gets crashed

Can you provide the App Service path mappings configuration file or explain about the App service that how you configure because it causes due to changes in the BYOS (Bring Your Own Storage) settings.

May be there's an automated process that is reattaching the Azure storage mount, causing your application to crash when the mount is reattached.


Your application was recycled as the BYOS storage settings changed.

Bring your own Azure Storage File share or Blob container into Azure Container Web App as network file share.

Use Azure CLI: az webapp config storage-account add --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --custom-id <custom-id> --storage-type <AzureFiles/AzureBlob> --share-name <share-name> --account-name <storage-account-name> --access-key "<access-key>" --mount-path <mount-path-directory>

You can integrate it with ARM template:
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "webApp_Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the webapp to configure"
            }
        },
        "webApp_Location": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location of the webapp to configure"
            }
        },
        "BYOS_mountName": {
            "defaultValue": "ARM-BYOS-mount",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Give your App Service mounted storage configuration a name."
            }
        },
        "BYOS_mountPath": {
            "defaultValue": "/home/byos_fileshare",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The location in the webapp filesystem that is mounted to the BYOS share."
            }
        },
        "AzureStorage_AccountName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the Azure Storage account to be used."
            }
        },
        "AzureStorage_ShareName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the azure file share to mount."
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "name": "[parameters('webApp_Name')]",
            "location": "[parameters('webApp_Location')]",
            "properties": {
                "siteConfig": {
                    "azureStorageAccounts": {
                        "[parameters('BYOS_mountName')]": {
                            "mountPath": "[parameters('BYOS_mountPath')]",
                            "accountName": "[parameters('AzureStorage_AccountName')]",
                            "type": "AzureFiles",
                            "shareName": "[parameters('AzureStorage_ShareName')]",
                            "accessKey": ""
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}


Now, the applications work fine even if the mount share exists.

